# How to increase database field value by 1 at refresh in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I search for this question but no one was able to solve my problem. This is my query for to increase database fied value. When I refresh page for first time then it automatically add 2 in one refresh but when I refresh second time then it doesn't update database value.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE mobile set view2=:view2+'1' WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->execute(array(':view2'=>$view2+1,':id'=>$id));
```

Help me. I'm new in PDO.

Comment: It's adding 2 because you've added 1 twice. Take the +'1' out of the top line and leave it in the bottom one. Besides, when you're using prepared statements you should do the manipulating of the variables outside of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the parameter at all:

```
UPDATE ... SET view2 = view2 + 1 WHERE ...
```

you can use a field in the record as a data source for updating any other field in the record, including itself.

Comment: can you please write exact query..?

Comment: the critical part is already above. if you can't cut/paste that, then...

Comment: I'm using PDO so please write it full code like I write above. If you can.